# How to increment a filename suffix in php

Tags: php, regex

My understanding of regex and working with strings in php is poor at best so my apologies if this is a simple question for most.  If I'm honest the searches I have made have confused me more than anything else, hopefully someone here can give me a clear answer.

I simply need to increment the suffix of file names in PHP.

The file names look like the following:

13132432343243432434234_1.jpg

I wish to keep the file name exactly as is, but replace the final '_1' part with '_2', '_3', '_4' etc.

There is no need to check if the file exists, this needs to be a simple string manipulation.  If the suffix is _1, then replace it with _2 and if the suffix is _4, then replace it with _5 etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: no need to check if the file exists? Then how do we know where to increment from?

Comment: Simply from the filename itself which is contained within a variable as a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something along these lines should do it:

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/(?<=_)\d+(?=\.)/',
                           function ($m) { return ++$m[0]; },
                           '13132432343243432434234_1.jpg');
```

The regex matches *"any number preceded by a `_` and followed by a `.`"*, the callback returns this number incremented by one.

Comment: Perfect and very simple...  All the answers here appear to work fine so huge thanks to all who answered.  However this appears to be the simplest solution of all.  Unless anyone else can see any way of breaking this method with certain filenames I will be accepting this answer.  Apologies to the others who answered so quickly.

Comment: Well, you can break it if the `_[number].` pattern appears anywhere else in the filename. You can tweak the regex in that case.

Comment: Thanks deceze I appreciate the clarity, in that case would Jeroen's or Dexters solution be the most foolproof method?

Comment: Not really. You can change the regex to something like `/(?<=_)\d+(?=\.[^.]+$)/` to make that pattern match only if it occurs at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without regex as well, using simple string functions:

```
$filename = '13132432343243432434234_1.jpg';

// Splits into '13132432343243432434234_1' and '.jpg'
list($name, $ext) = explode('.', $filename);

// Splits into '13132432343243432434234' and '1'
list($basename, $index) = explode('_', $name);

$index++; // increment the index

$filename = $basename . '_' . $index . '.' . $ext;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job.

```
<?php

$file = "13132432343243432434234_1.jpg"; // old filename

list ($fn,$ext) = preg_split("/\./",$file); // split name and extension

print_r(array($fn,$ext));

list($pre,$suffix) = preg_split("/_/",$fn); // split prefix and suffix

print_r(array($pre,$suffix));

$suffix++; // increment  by 1

$file = $pre . "_" . $suffix . $ext; // regroup

echo "NEW FILENAME: " . $file; // new filename

?>
```